# Process substitution in exported BASH functions not working in OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, gnu-parallel

Consider the following (admittedly ridiculous) minimal non-working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test_func() {
  echo "$1" \
    | tee >(cat - > test) \
    | cat }

export -f test_func

parallel test_func :::: <(seq 1 4)
```

Under BASH version 3.2.57(1)-release on OS X version 10.11.1, this yields the following errors:

```
sh: test_func: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: test_func: line 0: `test_func () {  echo "$1" | tee >(cat - > test) | cat -'
sh: error importing function definition for `test_func'
```

What, no process substitution in exported BASH functions in OS X?

Comment: It appears that parallel is running `sh` and not `bash`. That would be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts are too long for a comment, so I'm writing them up in an answer.

---

First, there seems to be a defect in Bash's Bourne shell emulation (note that `/bin/sh` on OS X is in fact Bash): it attempts to import functions exported in bash, which is clearly a source of errors. To test this:

```
> func () { echo 'Exported function leaked into sh.'; } && export -f func && /bin/sh -c func
Exported function leaked into sh.
```

For instance, a simple process substitution (not present in Bourne shell) will blow it away:

```
> func () { cat <(echo yay); } && export -f func && /bin/sh -c :
/bin/sh: func: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: func: line 0: `func () {  cat <(echo yay)'
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `func'
```

Note I didn't do anything in the `/bin/sh` subshell (I only ran `:`).

---

As for why you see these error messages when you run `parallel`, I suppose it's a problem of unnecessary invocation of `sh` on `parallel`'s part, somewhere in the chain. Note that the problem doesn't go away even if you hard code `SHELL` or even `PARALLEL_SHELL` (see man page for documentation of this environment variable), i.e., running `SHELL=/bin/bash parallel ...` or `PARALLEL_SHELL=/bin/bash parallel ...` doesn't help, so this is clearly a problem. However, `sh` (or Bash in `sh` emulation mode) does not attempt to read any startup files when invoked non-interactively, so it's kind of hard to collect definitive evidence of `sh` being invoked (even briefly) in the chain.

I don't have time to look through `parallel`'s 10k lines of source code to confirm my speculation (an odd one, for that matter; I don't see why `sh` should be invoked), so you should probably email bug-parallel@gnu.org or parallel@gnu.org to get some expert opinion. Parallel's [maintainer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363028/ole-tange) is also known to lurk around here.

Comment: It would appear that there is a malfunction related to parallel's handling of SHELL and PARALLEL_SHELL under OS X. I tried running parallel under Homebrew's most recent version of BASH (4.3) and hard-coding /usr/local/bin/bash in these two variables, and parallel once again used /bin/sh for subshells. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AdamKhan I can't reproduce actually. Your can confirm what shell is run by putting a `echo $BASH` in your function. In my case, when I run `SHELL=/bin/bash parallel` I get `/usr/local/bin/bash`, which clears contradicts the man page (but it's too bad), and when I run `PARALLEL_SHELL=/bin/bash parallel` I get `/bin/bash` as expected. Anyway, have you reported upstream? If so, could you keep us posted here? Thanks.

Comment: Whoops. My comment above is totally wrong, it's not a parallel problem. I used a non-trivial example function I'm familiar with (`func() { convert -density 300 -quiet "$1"[0] pbm:- | unpaper --overwrite /dev/stdin /dev/stdout | tee >(pnmtopng > test.png) | tesseract - - -l deu -psm 1; }`), which returns errors as above, but works perfectly. Could it be that the function definition is being imported into /bin/sh **and** into the shell under which the function will actually be run?

Comment: @AdamKhan Your successful execution is ultimately done in bash, yes. But `sh` is somehow involved in the process, which is unexpected; and due to the `sh` emulation defect of `bash` I outlined above the unexpected execution manifests itself as an error. That's the point.

Comment: @AdomKhan A little bit more about exporting functions: `export -f func` simply sets the env var `BASH_FUNC_func%%` (post-shellshock); you can confirm this by looking at the output of `env`. It's up to the subshell whether it is interpreted (and "imported") or not. For instance, `func () { cat <(echo yay); } && export -f func && /bin/zsh -c env` won't print an error, because zsh simply doesn't care about `BASH_FUNC_func%%`. But it's there in the env nevertheless, and if you start yet another bash subshell inside the zsh subshell, it will be imported.

Comment: For the record, I've submitted a bug report to the mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-parallel/2015-11/msg00001.html.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in git version [dd793ce] for most systems.

For dragonfly, freebsd, netbsd, qnx, and unixware you will need to set PARALLEL_SHELL:

```
PARALLEL_SHELL=/bin/bash parallel --onall -S bsdserver 'func() { cat <(echo bash only construct); };export -f func; parallel func ::: ' ::: 1
```

Comment: Actually the fix is in [3d919c6](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/commit/?id=3d919c6cd427e9615f56f260eb959a44d5d32c18).